# JQuery iteration over JSONs Map of lists generated via Scala Play 2.0

Tags: jquery, json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Given the following Scala in my Play Controller (reduced for the sake of brevity):

```
object Sample {
     def apply(someArgToBeUsedLater: String) = {
          val success = Map("foo" -> List("Things", "Stuff", "Test"))
          Ok(Json.toJson(success)).as("application/json")
     }
}
```

I would like to consume the resulting JSON on the Client-side, as follows (JQuery):

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Application.myFunc(someArgToBeUsedLater).ajax({success:     
     function(data) {
    $(data.foo).each(function(index) {
        $('#unorderedList').add("li").html(this);
    });
}});
```

while I would `this` to be a single String that, looking FireBug: the characters appear to be split out: `String { 0="T", 1="h", 2="i", more...}`

It seems that if I simply iterate using straight JavaScript (not using JQuery each()), then I wouldn't have a problem.  Hence, It appears I am simply using JQuery incorrectly.  On the other hand, I am relatively new to Scala and I am also wondering if I have correctly constructed the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Try $.each(data.foo, function(index){
...
})

$('data.foo') is a syntax for JQuery selectors to grab a part of a DOM.

Comment: I just tried this: same behavior.  Aren't both forms functionally identical?

Comment: Sorry. If you are unsure about Scala part, you can try to construct JSON explicitly, as it is specified at "Another way for constructing JSON" in https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaJson